# On Linux, SCTP associations hangs during shutdown when the closing end-point's IP address is deleted from the network interface

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, sctp

We have an SCTP association between two IP addresses on two different nodes, say A and B, both running Linux version 4.2. The following are my observations:

- On A, if you terminate the process containing the SCTP socket, the
  association clears up immediately from /proc/net/sctp/assocs if the
  corresponding IP address for end-point A is still present on the
  network device.
- On A, if you delete the IP address from the network device, and
  subsequently attempt to terminate the process, the association is
  still present under /proc/net/sctp/assocs up to 6 minutes after the
  process has been terminated.

Does anyone know if this is a bug or an expected behavior depending upon configuration settings, and could it be altered in a way that the association disappears immediately after the process containing the socket is terminated? Thanks!